# flawless answer but not accepted from longtime?

Tags: discussion

who will take care of the answers which were posted in Ask Ubuntu for a question and even they are proper and solved the OP problem if he didnt care at mark it as solved/accepted.

If there anything we can do with this issue , if we so what best we can do ?

Comment: I think that you're missing that accept doesn't really matter, and the system counts a couple of upvotes as resolved.  Accept rate != green check.

Comment: Vote on the good answer!

Comment: @JorgeCastro hi , yeah I am already doing that. But some of the questions not accepted even they have received proper answer.

Comment: There's not much you can do about it but vote, if people don't accept an answer they don't have to.

Comment: @JorgeCastro But how about having a team for that , I mean making it as one of the privilege and that can give for users who are above 50K reputation ? Because an user who got 50K reputation means we can say that he is extraordinary person so that he can decide. Just idea . hope you dont mind for that.

Comment: Yeah but what problem are you trying to solve? If the answer has enough votes it's considered answered already!

Answer (score 4):

There is something called Vote to Resolve, which is used if you consider that the answer is **Valid and Helpful** but you don't have more votes to upvote it, to take it from the unanswered list, then you can ask someone to vote it. Otherwise, you can vote yourself, or make your own answer.

This will take answers from the "Unanswered" list. And if the answer is exceptional, maybe it can get more votes, and you can use the bounty system to reward it.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it a fair extension of your question to also ask:**

- given that someone HAS accepted an answer, but done so mistakenly (not realizing that something else they did at / around the same time was actually the solution, or for some other reason, the situation was resolved by something other than the answer accepted, but the person was just not aware of this fact when they accepted a person's answer ... who will monitor that?

  **... and to then go on to attempt to answer both questions:**
- given that the business world benefits so greatly from this kind of a open learning / teaching / problem solving community, is it possible that a budget can be assigned for implementing a potential solution?

  **- and following on from that:**

  ... if so, who would organize & assess such things?